# Combining Two Files, Invalid use of nonstatic data member

Tags: c++, non-static, datamember

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DVD {
public:
    char m_strTitle[25];
    int m_nYearOfRelease;
    char m_strGenre[25];
    char m_strRentalStatus[50];
}

void Print()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Title" << DVD::m_strTitle << "YearOfRelease" << DVD::m_nYearOfRelease << "Genre" << DVD::m_strGenre
         << "RentalStatus" << DVD::m_strRentalStatus << endl;
}
```

This is my first file that generates 5 invalid use of non-static data member errors, and im not quite sure what that means, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated. I also want to combine it with another file in which i declare 10 DVD types, normally i would put them all as one file but the question that i am required to do for my assignment asks that i create an array of 10 DVDs and fill them using info from an input file, so here is the input file that i made as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// Set the Info for 10 DVDs
void SetInfo(const char* strTitle, int nYearOfRelease, const char* strGenre, const char* strRentalStatus) {
    strncpy(m_strTitle, strTitle, 25);
    m_nYearOfRelease = nYearOfRelease;
    strncpy(m_strGenre, strGenre, 25);
    strncpy(m_strRentalStatus, strRentalStatus, 50);
}

int main() {
    // Declare 10 DVDs
    DVD cInception;
    cInception.SetInfo("Inception", 2010, "Action", "In stock");

    DVD cFightClub;
    cFightClub.SetInfo("Fight Club", 1999, "Action/Suspense", "Due back November12th");

    DVD cPulpFiction;
    cPulpFiction.SetInfo("Pulp Fiction", 1994, "Action", "In Stock");

    DVD cTheDarkKnight;
    cTheDarkKnight.SetInfo("The Dark Knight", 2008, "Drama", "In Stock");

    DVD cAmericanHustle;
    cAmericanHustle.SetInfo("American Hustle", 2013, "Drama", "Due back December1st");

    DVD cSilverLiningsPlaybook;
    cSilverLiningsPlaybook.SetInfo("Silver Linings Playbook", 2012, "Drama/Romance", "In Stock");

    DVD cTheHungerGames;
    cTheHungerGames.SetInfo("The Hunger Games", 2012, "Adventure", "Due Back Today at 12pm");

    DVD cFurious7;
    cFurious7.SetInfo("Furious 7", 2015, "Action", "One Left in Stock");

    DVD cSavingPrivateRyan;
    cSavingPrivateRyan.SetInfo("Saving Private Ryan", 1998, "Drama/War", "Discontinued");

    DVD cGladiator;
    cGladiator.SetInfo("Gladiator", 2000, "Action", "In Stock");

    // Print out DVD Info
    cInception.Print();
    cFightClub.Print();
    cPulpFiction.Print();
    cTheDarkKnight.Print();
    cAmericanHustle.Print();
    cSilverLiningsPlaybook.Print();
    cTheHungerGames.Print();
    cFurious7.Print();
    cSavingPrivateRyan.Print();
    cGladiator.Print();

    return0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `void Print() {...}` definition into the `DVD` class definition, so it can act as a member function. You won't need `DVD::` prefixes for each member then.

**Regarding the files:** The simplest way to get it work is to put the fist code snippet into a header file, the second is your source file, where you `#include` that header.

You're also forgetting `;` after the class definition, I see `return0;`, and at this point, I'm stopping to look further.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either move your `Print()` definition into the `DVD` definition, or declare it inside the `DVD` definition and add the `DVD::` prefix before `Print()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `DVD` class members in that context to deal with issue you must rebuild your `Print` function in that principe to specify it as `DVD` class member the same is for `SetInfo` function.

```
void DVD::Print()
{
     using namespace std;
     cout << "Title" << m_strTitle << "YearOfRelease" << m_nYearOfRelease << "Genre" << m_strGenre <<
     "RentalStatus" << m_strRentalStatus << endl;
}
```

The entire declaration-defenition code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DVD 
{
    public:
    char m_strTitle[25];
    int m_nYearOfRelease;
    char m_strGenre[25];
    char m_strRentalStatus[50];
    void Print();
    void SetInfo(const char *strTitle, int nYearOfRelease, const char *strGenre, const char *strRentalStatus);
};

void DVD::Print()
{
     using namespace std;
     cout << "Title" << m_strTitle << "YearOfRelease" << m_nYearOfRelease << "Genre" << m_strGenre <<
     "RentalStatus" << m_strRentalStatus << endl;
}

// Set the Info for 10 DVDs
// Also DVD class member function
void DVD::SetInfo(const char *strTitle, int nYearOfRelease, const char *strGenre, const char *strRentalStatus) 
{
     strncpy(m_strTitle, strTitle, 25);
     m_nYearOfRelease = nYearOfRelease;
     strncpy(m_strGenre, strGenre, 25);
     strncpy(m_strRentalStatus, strRentalStatus, 50);
}

int main()
{
     //Declare 10 DVDs
     DVD cInception;
     cInception.SetInfo("Inception", 2010, "Action", "In stock");

     DVD cFightClub;
     cFightClub.SetInfo("Fight Club", 1999, "Action/Suspense", "Due back November12th");

     DVD cPulpFiction;
     cPulpFiction.SetInfo("Pulp Fiction", 1994, "Action", "In Stock");

     DVD cTheDarkKnight;
     cTheDarkKnight.SetInfo("The Dark Knight", 2008, "Drama", "In Stock");

     DVD cAmericanHustle;
     cAmericanHustle.SetInfo("American Hustle", 2013, "Drama", "Due back December1st");

     DVD cSilverLiningsPlaybook;
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.SetInfo("Silver Linings Playbook", 2012, "Drama/Romance", "In Stock");

     DVD cTheHungerGames;
cTheHungerGames.SetInfo("The Hunger Games", 2012, "Adventure", "Due Back Today at 12pm");

     DVD cFurious7;
     cFurious7.SetInfo("Furious 7", 2015, "Action", "One Left in Stock");

     DVD cSavingPrivateRyan;
     cSavingPrivateRyan.SetInfo("Saving Private Ryan", 1998, "Drama/War", "Discontinued");

     DVD cGladiator;
     cGladiator.SetInfo("Gladiator", 2000, "Action", "In Stock");

     //Print out DVD Info

     cInception.Print();
     cFightClub.Print();
     cPulpFiction.Print();
     cTheDarkKnight.Print();
     cAmericanHustle.Print();
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.Print();
     cTheHungerGames.Print();
     cFurious7.Print();
     cSavingPrivateRyan.Print();
     cGladiator.Print();

     return 0; // fix return statement member
}
```

To create your program as different translation units.

The class declaration must be in DVD.h

```
#ifndef __DVD_H__
#define __DVD_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DVD 
{
    public:
    char m_strTitle[25];
    int m_nYearOfRelease;
    char m_strGenre[25];
    char m_strRentalStatus[50];
    void Print();
    void SetInfo(const char *strTitle, int nYearOfRelease, const char *strGenre, const char *strRentalStatus);
};

#endif /* __DVD_H__ */
```

Defenition of DVD class methods in DVD.cpp

```
#include "DVD.h"

void DVD::Print()
{
     using namespace std;
     cout << "Title" << m_strTitle << "YearOfRelease" << m_nYearOfRelease << "Genre" << m_strGenre <<
     "RentalStatus" << m_strRentalStatus << endl;
}

// Set the Info for 10 DVDs
// Also DVD class member function
void DVD::SetInfo(const char *strTitle, int nYearOfRelease, const char *strGenre, const char *strRentalStatus) 
{
     strncpy(m_strTitle, strTitle, 25);
     m_nYearOfRelease = nYearOfRelease;
     strncpy(m_strGenre, strGenre, 25);
     strncpy(m_strRentalStatus, strRentalStatus, 50);
}
```

than in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DVD.h"

int main()
{
     //Declare 10 DVDs
     DVD cInception;
     cInception.SetInfo("Inception", 2010, "Action", "In stock");

     DVD cFightClub;
     cFightClub.SetInfo("Fight Club", 1999, "Action/Suspense", "Due back November12th");

     DVD cPulpFiction;
     cPulpFiction.SetInfo("Pulp Fiction", 1994, "Action", "In Stock");

     DVD cTheDarkKnight;
     cTheDarkKnight.SetInfo("The Dark Knight", 2008, "Drama", "In Stock");

     DVD cAmericanHustle;
     cAmericanHustle.SetInfo("American Hustle", 2013, "Drama", "Due back December1st");

     DVD cSilverLiningsPlaybook;
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.SetInfo("Silver Linings Playbook", 2012, "Drama/Romance", "In Stock");

     DVD cTheHungerGames;
cTheHungerGames.SetInfo("The Hunger Games", 2012, "Adventure", "Due Back Today at 12pm");

     DVD cFurious7;
     cFurious7.SetInfo("Furious 7", 2015, "Action", "One Left in Stock");

     DVD cSavingPrivateRyan;
     cSavingPrivateRyan.SetInfo("Saving Private Ryan", 1998, "Drama/War", "Discontinued");

     DVD cGladiator;
     cGladiator.SetInfo("Gladiator", 2000, "Action", "In Stock");

     //Print out DVD Info

     cInception.Print();
     cFightClub.Print();
     cPulpFiction.Print();
     cTheDarkKnight.Print();
     cAmericanHustle.Print();
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.Print();
     cTheHungerGames.Print();
     cFurious7.Print();
     cSavingPrivateRyan.Print();
     cGladiator.Print();

     return 0; // fix return statement member
}
```

to work with file we must define new DVD class method

```
// Defile new class method
void DVD::SetInfo(std::istream& stream) 
{         
     // Read title
     stream.getline(m_strTitle, 25);
     // Read year of release
     stream >> m_nYearOfRelease 
     // Read genre
     stream.getline(m_strGenre, 25);
     // Read rental status
     stream.getline(m_strRentalStatus, 50);
}
```

so in main.cpp we got this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DVD.h"

int main()
{
     std::ifstream input_file("filename.txt");
     DVD cInception;
     cInception.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cFightClub;
     cFightClub.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cPulpFiction;
     cPulpFiction.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cTheDarkKnight;
     cTheDarkKnight.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cAmericanHustle;
     cAmericanHustle.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cSilverLiningsPlaybook;
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cTheHungerGames;
     cTheHungerGames.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cFurious7;
     cFurious7.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cSavingPrivateRyan;
     cSavingPrivateRyan.SetInfo(input_file);

     DVD cGladiator;
     cGladiator.SetInfo(input_file);

     //Print out DVD Info

     cInception.Print();
     cFightClub.Print();
     cPulpFiction.Print();
     cTheDarkKnight.Print();
     cAmericanHustle.Print();
     cSilverLiningsPlaybook.Print();
     cTheHungerGames.Print();
     cFurious7.Print();
     cSavingPrivateRyan.Print();
     cGladiator.Print();

     return 0; // fix return statement member
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my code now works and compiles fine and displays what i desire, however what could it mean when my instructor wants me to test it using an input file, i am a little unclear on this

Comment: @Scott Glendenning: I am unclear too. May be he or she wants to load input data about DVDs from file.

Comment: How would i accomplish this, loading the input data about DVDs from file?

Comment: Its like inputing from cin. The only difference is you must create object like cin explicity `std::istream file_cin("filename")` so to load info integer from file you could call `file_cin >> <some_integer>`. Other operations is like you did with `cin`.

Comment: The input values you could type in some sort of simple text file like `*.txt`

Comment: So instead of in 'int main()'  declaring 10 DVD's i put 'std::istream file_cin("filename.txt")' as my main function? With the text file containing all the required info for my DVD